# Im not receiving the email verification in order to activate the user created

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Please I've created an authentication system where a user can login with both username and email address.
The account is deactivated when it is created. I want the user to confirm his email before the account is
activated. I used the django email verification but although the user is created successfully, I dont receive
the email. Please help.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
```

backend.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q

UserModel = get_user_model()

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(
                Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return User.objects.filter(email=username).order_by('id').first()
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None

    return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django import forms
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from .models import CustomUser
from django_email_verification import send_email
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2') 

@receiver(pre_save, sender=CustomUser)

def set_new_user_inactive(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance._state.adding is True:
        instance.is_active = False
        
    else:
        pass

class MyClassView(FormView):

def form_valid(self, form):
    CustomUser = form.save()
    returnVal = super(MyClassView, self).form_valid(form)
    send_email(CustomUser)
    return returnVal

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Email / Username')
```

project url

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
#new
from django_email_verification import urls as email_urls


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('email/', include(email_urls)),

    
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser' # new

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['accounts.backends.EmailBackend'] # new
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''


DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ''

def verified_callback(CustomUser):
    CustomUser.is_active = True


EMAIL_VERIFIED_CALLBACK = verified_callback
EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS = 'noreply@aliasaddress.com'
EMAIL_MAIL_SUBJECT = 'Confirm your email'
EMAIL_MAIL_HTML = 'mail_body.html'
EMAIL_MAIL_PLAIN = 'mail_body.txt'
EMAIL_TOKEN_LIFE = 60 * 60
EMAIL_PAGE_TEMPLATE = 'confirm_template.html'
EMAIL_PAGE_DOMAIN = ''
```

Comment: Have you set at least `EMAIL_HOST` and `EMAIL_PORT` in your settings file?

Comment: yes please. I've edited indicating whats in my settings.py file

Comment: I guess you are using `django_email_verification` package? Which I, unfortunately, don't know :/

Comment: Thanks for your response. which approach do you recommend then with examples pls